# Parsing Firebase JSON F#

Tags: json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, f#, json.net

I'm trying to convert the following Firebase JSON into something that can be parsed in `F#`:

```
{  
   "listings":{  
      "-L0pJmU9yj4hAocHjnrB":{  
         "listing_id":"-L0pJmU9yj4hAocHjnrB",
         "location":"Edinburgh",
         "messages":{  
            "SWs56OIGzMdiCjSXahzDQX8zve92":{  
               "-L3ELSSzZPRdjCRcFTrb":{  
                  "senderId":"SWs56OIGzMdiCjSXahzDQX8zve92",
                  "senderName":"alberto",
                  "text":"Hi"
               },
               "-L3EN1NW5hHWBTEGC9ve":{  
                  "senderId":"YMM45tgFFvYB7rx9PhC2TE5eW6D2",
                  "senderName":"David",
                  "text":"Hey"
               }
            }
         }
      },
      "-L19C5OjcDSjMi4-oha-":{  
         "listing_id":"-L19C5OjcDSjMi4-oha-",
         "location":"Edinburgh"
      },
      "-L19CJrzEpChO_W14YkC":{  
         "listing_id":"-L19CJrzEpChO_W14YkC",
         "location":"Edinburgh",
         "messages":{  
            "Rp7ytJdEvZeMFgpLqeCSzkSeTyf1":{  
               "-L19V4QpPMCMwGcNaQBG":{  
                  "senderId":"Rp7ytJdEvZeMFgpLqeCSzkSeTyf1",
                  "senderName":"Albert",
                  "text":"Hey there"
               },
               "-L19r0osoet4f9SjBGE7":{  
                  "senderId":"YMM45tgFFvYB7rx9PhC2TE5eW6D2",
                  "senderName":"David",
                  "text":"Hi"
               },
               "-L3ELGAbcOjdJsHRtnAe":{  
                  "senderId":"YMM45tgFFvYB7rx9PhC2TE5eW6D2",
                  "senderName":"David",
                  "text":"Icvjv"
               }
            }
         }
      },
      "-L19ChjPjX1DnfQb28AW":{  
         "listing_id":"-L19ChjPjX1DnfQb28AW",
         "location":"Edinburgh",
         "messages":{  
            "879dUqGuiXSd95QHzfhbSs05IZn2":{  
               "-L1i6c7sGf3BcF2cCSCu":{  
                  "senderId":"879dUqGuiXSd95QHzfhbSs05IZn2",
                  "senderName":"Alberto",
                  "text":"Hello"
               }
            },
            "Rp7ytJdEvZeMFgpLqeCSzkSeTyf1":{  
               "-L19FGCMuQACjYKCFEwV":{  
                  "senderId":"Rp7ytJdEvZeMFgpLqeCSzkSeTyf1",
                  "senderName":"Albert",
                  "text":"Hey"
               },
               "-L19T_v2Utxhu1mGhz7-":{  
                  "senderId":"YMM45tgFFvYB7rx9PhC2TE5eW6D2",
                  "senderName":"David",
                  "text":"Hi"
               },
               "-L19TbhActGmga4f47Mz":{  
                  "senderId":"Rp7ytJdEvZeMFgpLqeCSzkSeTyf1",
                  "senderName":"Albert",
                  "text":"How are you"
               }
            }
         }
      },
      "-L19Cz1abm1o-JCbiAnN":{  
         "listing_id":"-L19Cz1abm1o-JCbiAnN",
         "location":"Edinburgh"
      },
      "-L19DMdFx2pXj9-EKCq2":{  
         "listing_id":"-L19DMdFx2pXj9-EKCq2",
         "location":"Edinburgh"
      },
      "-L19DV67WjguozFE_4dM":{  
         "listing_id":"-L19DV67WjguozFE_4dM",
         "location":"Edinburgh"
      }
   }
}
```

The problem here is that the entries like `L0pJmU9yj4hAocHjnrB` in the 2nd line and subsequent similar entries are autogenerated timestamp IDs created in Firebase, and they do not have a corresponding name, like for example: `"listing_id":"-L0pJmU9yj4hAocHjnrB"`, therefore I do not know how to set up my `F#` Records to correctly parse this JSON.

My attempt can be seen below:

```
type MessageContent = 
    { senderId: string
      senderName: string
      text: string; }

type Message =
     { timestampId : string
       chatMessages : MessageContent;}

type Chat = 
    { chatPartnerId : string 
      Messages : Message array option;}

type ListingContent = 
    { from : string
      landlord_id : string
      listing_id : string
      location : string
      name : string
      pic_1_url : string
      pic_2_url : string
      pic_3_url : string
      pic_4_url : string
      pic_5_url : string
      messages : Chat array option
      postcode : string
      price_per_night : int
      to_date : string;
    }

type Listing =
     { timestampId : string
       listingcontent : ListingContent option;}

type City = 
    { city : string
      listings : Listing array option
    }

type AllListings = 
    { cities : City array;}

type SearchSettings = 
    { from : string
      location : string
      max_price : decimal
      min_price : decimal
      to_date : string;}

type MatchContent = 
    { id : string
      location : string;}

type Match = 
    {timestampId : string
     matchContent : MatchContent;}

type DeclinedContent = 
    { id : string;
      }

type Declined = 
    {timestampId : string
     declinedContent : DeclinedContent;}

type ListingUserContent = 
    { listing_id : string
      location : string
      messages : Chat array option;
    }

type ListingUser = 
    {timestampId : string
     listingUser : ListingUserContent;}

type UserContent = 
    { declined: Declined option
      matches : Match option
      search_settings : SearchSettings option
      listings : ListingUser option;
    }
```

I use the following code for parsing:

```
    let myCallbackGetChats (reader:IO.StreamReader) url = 
    let html = reader.ReadToEnd()
    let reader = new JsonTextReader(reader);
    let serializer = JsonSerializer.Create(JsonSerializerSettings(Converters = [| Types.OptionConverter() |]))
    use stringReader = new StringReader(html)
    use jsonReader = new JsonTextReader(stringReader)
    let listings_json = serializer.Deserialize<Types.UserContent>(jsonReader)
    printfn "%A" listings_json
```

This produces the following output:

```
    {declined = null;
 matches = null;
 search_settings = null;
 listings = Some {listing_id = null;
                  location = null;
                  messages = null;};}
```

As we can see the first `listings` tag is properly deserialized, however as soon as it sees `L0pJmU9yj4hAocHjnrB` it doesn't know what that is and the rest of the parsing fails. How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can deserialize your JSON with the following F# types:

```
type MessageContent = 
    { senderId: string
      senderName: string
      text: string; 
    }

type ListingContent = 
    { listing_id : string
      location : string
      messages : Map<string, Map<string, MessageContent>>
      // Add other members as required
    }

type UserContent =
    { listings: Map<string, ListingContent>
      // Add other members as required
    }
```

And the following line of code:

```
let listings_json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UserContent>(inputJson)
```

Notes:

- The `"listing"` object consists of variable property names with a fixed schema for their values.  As explained in [*Serialization Guide: Dictionaries and Hashtables*](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/serializationguide.htm#Dictionarys) such objects can be mapped to a .Net dictionary.  In this case I chose the F# [`Collections.Map<'Key,'Value>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/collections.map%5b%27key%2c%27value%5d-class-%5bfsharp%5d) class, specifically a `Map<string, ListingContent>`.
- Similarly, the `"messages"` object consists of variable property names whose values are a nested level of objects with variable property names, and so can be represented with a `Map<string, Map<string, MessageContent>>`.
- I simplified the `UserContent` and `ListingContent` types by removing members not actually present in the sample JSON.  You can add them back as required.
- Since Json.NET has built-in support for dictionaries, a custom `JsonConverter` is not required for this solution.

Example working [F# fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Cu7h1Y).